# Export Windows XP event logs cmd

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch, event-log, event-viewer

I need to export a specific Windows XP event log from the eventviewer to a ".txt" file.

My scenario is that the user programs a chkdsk to be execute on next reboot into a remote machine, and after that he needs to retrieve the results from the eventvwr/event log.

I found this cmd solution for Windows 7 which is perfect and exactly what I'm looking for (I store this batch in the remote machine and execute it remotely):

```
cd c:\
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
powershell -Command "& {get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname='Application'; id='1001'}| ?{$_.providername -match 'wininit'} | fl timecreated, message | out-file C:\MessageServer\chkdsk_log_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt}"
```

I like it a lot, but it doesn't works on Windows XP because it doesn't have powershell or wevutil tools by default... And I believe I need them to retrieve this information. If I'm wrong please let me know.

I need to program a solution for both, Windows 7 and XP. It have to be done by batch or java solution but I cannot install any extra tool in the machine (like powershell) in order to do this.

Do you have any ideas?

All my best and thanks in advance!

Carlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link:
http://www.windows-commandline.com/event-viewer-command-line/

> We can open event viewer console from command prompt or from Run window by running the command eventvwr.  To retrieve the events information from log files in command line we can use eventquery.vbs. This file can be found in the directory C:\Windows\System32.
>
> Using eventquery.vbs we can dump the events selectively based on various parameters. These parameters include event source, event id, event date, event type(information, error , warning), event log file name(system, application, security, IE etc). Below are few examples on how to use this script file.

hope this helps!

Comment: At the end i use the following code:

cd c:\Windows\System32
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
cscript //h:cscript //s
regsvr32 /s cmdlib.wsc
cscript C:\windows\system32\eventquery.vbs
Cscript Eventquery.vbs /l application /fi "ID eq 1001" /fi "SOURCE eq Winlogon" /V > C:\MessageServer\chkdsk_log_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log

Comment: This code doesn't retrieve all event description. It seems more like a picture of the dialog box of description. I need to get only the full description. Any idea? 
Do I doing something wrong?

Comment: Glad i was able to help you. If this answers your question please mark it as accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ok then!!!

I use the following code (almost the same of my comment to Jakob answer):

```
cd c:\Windows\System32
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
cscript //h:cscript //s
regsvr32 /s cmdlib.wsc
cscript C:\windows\system32\eventquery.vbs
Cscript Eventquery.vbs /l application /fi "ID eq 1001" /fi "SOURCE eq Winlogon" /V > C:\MessageServer\chkdsk_log_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.csv
```

The trick was to change the file type where I put the data, from .log to .csv
So I can open it with a text editor and get full info and full description which is what I was looking for.

Hope this helps to someone else too!

All my bests!!!

Comment: Sorry, on the last row of code of my answer I forgot to put `/fo csv` before >
All the rest is perfect XD